# Unable to get out of ORA-00907 error

Tags: oracle, ora-00907

I am getting the missing right paranthesis error. If I remove the comments around iterator.next() statement, its working fine. Unable to figure out whats wrong. There is NO "(" in the data I pass.

```
String ORACLE_SUM_QUERY = "select item_number, sum(system_quantity) from ITEMS " +
        "where sndate = ? and item_id in" +
        " (select item_id from ap.system_items where org_id = 4 " +
        " and segment1 in "; 
......
 while (iterator.hasNext()) {
//iterator.next();
String oracleQuery = String.format(ORACLE_SUM_QUERY + "(%s)) GROUP BY item_number", iterator.next());
        preparedStat = connection.prepareStatement(oracleQuery);
        preparedStat.setDate(1, getSnDate());
```

Comment: Where is the right-brace which matches the left brace in `while (iterator.hasNext()) {`?

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to indicate that the SQL statement you are building up in `oracleQuery` has an incorrect number of parenthesis.  It would probably be helpful to print that SQL statement out before passing it to the `prepareStatement` call to make debugging easier.

My guess is that the string that is returned by `iterator.next()` is not what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting your code as

```
String ORACLE_SUM_QUERY = "select item_number, sum(system_quantity) from ITEMS " +
        "where sndate = ? and item_id in" +
        " (select item_id from ap.system_items where org_id = 4 " +
        " and segment1 in ("; 
......
 while (iterator.hasNext())
   {
   ORACLE_SUM_QUERY = ORACLE_SUM_QUERY + String.format("%s", iterator.next());

   if(iterator.hasNext())
     ORACLE_SUM_QUERY = ORACLE_SUM_QUERY + ",";
   }

ORACLE_SUM_QUERY = ORACLE_SUM_QUERY + ")) GROUP BY item_number";

preparedStat = connection.prepareStatement(ORACLE_SUM_QUERY);
preparedStat.setDate(1, getSnDate());
```

This may not get it exactly as I can't test it, but it might get you closer.

Share and enjoy.